# I have two forms in a page. How to set the jQuery script not to affect both forms buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I have 2 forms. he jQuery scripts disables both buttons of the forms, until one dropdown value is selected as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/baW53/

The problem is that I need to activate only the button where the dropdown value is changed/selected. For now if I choose a value on the first form, it activates the button of the second form also. But it has to activate only the same form's button.

How to do this?

```
var jq = $.noConflict();

jq(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    jq('select').change(validate);
});

function validate(e){

    var validation = true;
    jq('select').each(function(){ 

        if(jq(this).val().length>0)
        {
            validation = false;
        }
    });   

    if ( validation ) {
        jq('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

    } else {

        jq('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}

<form name="forma" method="POST" action="used-results.php" id="apliforma">
dropdown menus
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" id='submit' >submit</button>
</form>

<form name="forma2" method="POST" action="used-results.php" id="sinthetiforma">
dropdown menus
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" id='submit2' >submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your javascript.

Comment: @cale_b I have updated my question with it. I have it fully working on the jsfiddle link so i thought it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use selectors like others say. Here's the modification to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baW53/1/

Basically, if its the initial call, we change the properties of all the buttons, i.e, buttons with class `submit` else we find the button which is a sibling of the dropdown and use its id.

Here's the relevant portion:

```
if (e) {
        var btn = "#" + jq(this).siblings('button').attr('id');
} else {
        var btn = ".submit";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it has a strange behaviour when I return the value back to None. At first it does not disables the button.

Comment: That's because the validate method checks for the value of BOTH the dropdowns and not the one that was changed. Here's a quick fix: http://jsfiddle.net/baW53/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting every submit button with this selector `jq('.submit')` you need to make it more specific.  There are any number of ways to do this.

One way is to get the select control from your event object then write a pattern to go to it's parent form and then down to the select button.

Getting the closest form:
[jQuery find parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621714/jquery-find-parent-form)

`jq(ev).closest("form").find(".submit")`

I'm not sure that `ev` is right, you might have to dig the control out of the event.

Comment: I am trying to make it work, but I can't. Can you make it on the fiddle I postes please?

Answer (score 0):

You can find specific elements with more complex selectors. For instance, if you gave your forms `id="forma"` and `id="formb"` you could do `jq(#forma .submit)` to get the one button.

If you stick with the `name` attribute, I believe the selector would be `jq([name="forma"] .submit)` or something close to that.