# get Form Name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form name="FNAME">  
    <div id="div1">  
        <ul id="ul1"><li id="li1"><a href="" onclick="getValue(this);">Click</a>  </li></ul>
    </div>  
</form>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(elem) {
        formName = $(elem.form.name).val();
        alert(formName);
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to get the form name of the above code:
        formName is undefined using above code
        How could i get the value of form name inside the javascript function?

Comment: This might help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621714/jquery-find-parent-form and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991367/how-to-get-the-form-parent-of-an-input

Comment: Thanx @ShrinivasShukla .This also works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery for cross browser support

```js
function getValue(elem) {
  var formName = $(elem).closest('form').attr('name')
  alert(formName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FNAME">
  <div id="div1">
    <ul id="ul1">
      <li id="li1">
        <a href="" onclick="getValue(this); return">Click</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: for elem.form.name showing error as cannot read property 'name' and $(elem).closest('form').attr('name') value is still showing undefined

Comment: its working here but in my code it showing error let me check again

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) like,

```
function getValue(elem)    
{    
    formName=$(elem).closest('form').attr('name');  
    alert(formName);  
}
```

```js
function getValue(elem) {
  formName = $(elem).closest('form').attr('name');
  alert(formName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FNAME">
  <div id="div1">
    <ul id="ul1">
      <li id="li1"><a href="" onclick="getValue(this);">Click</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, bind on click event using jquery like,

```
$(function(){
   $('#li1').on('click','a',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).closest('form').attr('name'));
   });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
   $('#li1').on('click','a',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($(this).closest('form').attr('name'));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FNAME">
  <div id="div1">
    <ul id="ul1">
      <li id="li1"><a href="" onclick="getValue(this);">Click</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: See my working snippet. Also Try my Alternate solution, which will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply from form tag.

`var formName = $('form')[0].name;
 alert(formName);`