# How to get $_POST value after Javascript POST in PHP?

Tags: javascript, post, submit

Hello there i want to ask how i can get print the $POST value from HTML from after Javascript post?

Here is my HTML submit forms:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./comments.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="addCommentContainer">
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost" />
<textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="add-comment-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="addCommentContainer">
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost" />
<textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="add-comment-submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".add-comment-submit").on("click", function (e) {



    e.preventDefault();



    var submit = $(this);



    if (submit.hasClass("working")) return false;



    submit.addClass("working");

    submit.val("Working...");



    $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

        submit.removeClass("working");

        submit.val("Submit");

        $("<div></div>").html(msg).fadeIn("slow").insertBefore(submit.parent($(".addCommentContainer"))).slideDown();

    });

});

});
```

Here is my submit.php which is printing "Hello World" after submit:

```
<?PHP 
$message = 'Hello World';
echo $message;
?>
```

**I don't know why but it seems it's not posting the information on submit.php or i am at wrong somewhere because when i try this in submit.php:**

```
<?PHP 
$message = $_POST["body"];
echo $message;
?>
```

It's not printing what is typed in the text area with name "body". How i make it print what is writen in the body input text area?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your ids should be unique in a page..why ur repeating the same form twice ?

Comment: Because i have many forms from which it must be submited and post the result only before the submited form.

Comment: In your `submit.php`, what does `print_r($_POST);` print?

Comment: when i prlace `$message = print_r($_POST);
echo $message;` It's printing `Array ( ) 1` WTF?

Comment: Just put in `print_r($_POST);`, nothing else. It just returns `true`, not the content of the array.

Comment: In this case - `<?PHP 
print_r($_POST);
?>` On submit it's giving `Array ( )` Why it's not posting the info in submit.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` inside the trigger, but the trigger is on the button, not the form, so `this` references the button. This also means that you are serializing the button not the form. Try this POST call in stead:

```
$.post('submit.php',$(this).parent().serialize(), ...
```

**EDIT:**

By the way, it is usually better practice to add the trigger to the form, e.g. as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311579/jquery-js-how-do-i-select-the-parent-form-based-on-which-submit-button-is-cli).